# webviewclient when loading HTTPS webpages

Tags: android, android-webview, webviewclient

I am having a webview , and webviewclient enabled for it. I have observed that
1.When loading HTTP pages the call flow is like  onPageStarted > shouldOverrideUrlLoading >onPageFinished
So here its working as expected.

2.While loading HTTPS pages code flow is   onPageStarted >onPageFinished > shouldOverrideUrlLoading > onPageStarted > onPageFinished

Because of which i am facing some issues.Is this android issue?.Is there any way to fix it from application side?

Answer (score 0):

The usual flow is: shouldInterceptRequest -> shouldOverrideUrlLoading -> onPageStarted -> onPageFinished/onReceivedError.

The behavior you're seeing on HTTPS is probably a redirect. Try logging the URLs in the callbacks to check whether this is the case.